# TypeError: PCA() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_components'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

Hi I was trying to implement the PCA(), but I'm getting an error, '

> TypeError: PCA() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_components'.

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
#Principal component analysis
def PCA(X,Y):
    pca = PCA(n_components=2)
    X = pca.fit_transform(X)

    plot_2d_space(X, Y, 'Imbalanced dataset (2 PCA components)')
```

Can someone please tell me a possible reason for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you are importing `from sklearn.decomposition import PCA`
and then you're using same name for your function `def PCA`

So next time you'll call the function, it will call your function not from the `scikit-learn` function.

So basically  `pca = PCA(n_components=2)` expects the arguments X and Y where you're passing `n_components`.

**Solution**:

Change the name of your function and it should work:

```
def PCA_2(X,Y):
    pca = PCA(n_components=2)
    X = pca.fit_transform(X)

    plot_2d_space(X, Y, 'Imbalanced dataset (2 PCA components)')
```